# Mover uma <div>

Tags: javascript, html, css

Como eu poderia mover essa DIV usando javascript?

```js
function randomization() {
    var randomValue = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 5);
    return randomValue;
  }

function playerMovement(direction) {
  switch (direction) {
    case 1:
      // Andar pra direita
      document.getElementById("player").src = "wlk.jpeg";
      break;
    case 2:
      // Andar pra esquerda
      document.getElementById("player").src = "wlk.jpeg";
      break;
    case 3:
      // Andar pra cima
      document.getElementById("player").src = "wlk.jpeg";
      break;
    case 4:
      // Andar pra baixo
      document.getElementById("player").src = "wlk.jpeg";
      break;
    case 5:
      // Atacar
      document.getElementById("player").src = "atk.png";
      break;
  }
}

function loop() {
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    playerMovement(randomization());
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  background: url("http://htmlcolorcodes.com/assets/images/html-color-codes-color-tutorials-hero-00e10b1f.jpg") no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img id="player" src="wlk.jpeg" width=100 height=100>
</div>
```

Comment: Dá uma olhada no animate do Jquery http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: Mover? Mover como? Seja mais específico em sua pergunta.